# Default SharedPreference value being set weirdly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Say in version 1, I do not have this `SharedPreference` value.
Now, I manually updated the APK to version 2. After that I re-boot my phone. However, when I adb pull the .xml file that was created, it is set as false.

SharedPreference as below:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean optimus = prefs.getBoolean("prime", true);
```

I thought `getBoolean` sets the value as the default value it it does not exist (which doesn't. It's the first time it's being initialized).

This xml file is completely new and it did not exist before.

Why does this happen? Is there some native Android behavior I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

`getBoolean(key, defaultValue)` returns the `defaultValue` programmatically when this Java statement is executed if there is no value in the XML file for this key, so you won't find the defaultValue in the XML file you're talking about unless you call `prefs.edit().putBoolean(key, myValue).apply()`

**Edit:** In other words, `prefs.getBoolean("prime", true)` will always return `true` UNLESS you once called `prefs.edit().putBoolean("prime", false).apply()` at any point in time (from the time you installed the first version of the application and assuming you never uninstalled it or cleared data).

Comment: so what is the value set as when I use this boolean: say
if (optimus == true)
run()

it wouldn't execute run(), correct?

Comment: Check my edited answer. And to answer the question in the comment, `if (optimus == true)` which can be simplified to `if (optimus)` will be true, and `run()` will be executed normally **unless** you edited the shared preferences and set `prime` to `false` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you update the application (without first uninstalling), it will keep the preference that has been set in the previous version. So if `"prime"` was set to `false` previously in the old version then it will still be `false` in  the new version, unless the old version is uninstalled first, before installing the new one. Uninstalling would delete the old preferences xml file.

Also, rebooting your phone will not clear preferences.